# Range filter in openSearch, ElasticSearch is not working correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, opensearch

I have a problem while using Opensearch which based on Elasticsearch  when I use range as filter query I get all the data that apply to the filter query despite it doesn't match the search query with a score of 0.0 down below sample of the query I use

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
            "match": {
              "FIELD": "TEXT"
            }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                 "FIELD": "TEXT"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                 "match": {
                 "FIELD": "TEXT"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                 "FIELD": "TEXT"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "FIELD": {
              "gt": 1,
              "lt": 500
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

what I want is to get all the data that only match the search Query and it matches the filter at the same time and I don't know what I'm doing wrong
any help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html i thinck you need to specify minimum_should_match to 2 or add a must query in the filter part.